# How to convert format csv to kaggle submission format in rapidminer

Tags: csv, machine-learning, export-to-csv, rapidminer, kaggle

I am trying to complete [San Francisco Crime Classification kaggle excercise](https://www.kaggle.com/c/sf-crime/data) with Rapidminer but I don't find any help on how to create a csv in kaggle submission format from rapidminer.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the example set containing the results you need to export using the `Write CSV` operator. This will create columns in the CSV file with names matching the names of the example set attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit the output of your trained model (on the test dataset). The submission matrix will have dimensions like 87k * 40. 1 column for the Id and 39 columns should be the total number of applicable predictions (crime types) and for each example, the row will be filled with the probabilities of each crime type (prediction probability). Columns should be labeled as follows:

> `Id`    `WARRANTS` `...` `LARCENY`

i.e the first column for Id and the rest for Crime types

Answer (score 0):

Use `Write CSV` operator in Rapidminer to convert thedata